# What is the default chunk size used when uploading blobs using the Azure CLI, and can this be changed?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-cli

I am using the Azure Command Line Interface `az` command to upload data to an Azure storage account:

```
az storage blob upload ...
```

I note the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/blob?view=azure-cli-latest) refers to "automatic chunking":

> Upload a file to a storage blob.
>
> Creates a new blob from a file path, or updates the content of an
> existing blob with automatic chunking and progress notifications.

What chunk size is used? Is it a fixed size or does it depend on other factors?

I would like to increase the chunk size to as large a value as possible, so that I can minimize Write Operation costs when uploading large files. Is this possible using the CLI tools?

Comment: Logic would make you think that a large chunk size would be better. In reality, you want a small chunk size as smaller chunk sizes have better transfer success rates.

Answer (score 1):

Default chunk size used is 4MB however it is automatically adjusted to either 100MB or 4000MB if it detects that the limit of 50000 blocks (maximum number allowed in a block blob) will be exceeded.

For example if the size of the file is more than 4 * 50000 * 1024 * 1024 bytes, then the chunk size used will be 100MB and if the file size is more than 100 * 50000 * 1024 * 1024 bytes, then the chunk size used will be 4000MB (maximum value allowed for a block).

I don’t think you can change this setting.